# How to fix my repository pattern when offline with mvvm

Tags: android, mvvm

I am creating very simple android app using mvvm and repository pattern. It fetch data from network (using retrofit2/RxJava2) if app is online and saves to DB (using room) and post to observe. If app is offline, app gets the data from DB and post to observe. From activity app updates the textviews after getting observed from viewmodel class.

Everything is working very fine when app has active internet connection. When internet is not available it does not load data from DB. And that's the problem am facing with no clue.

Activity class

```
viewModel.loadHomeData();
        viewModel.homeDataEntityResult().observe(this, this::updateTextViews);

private void updateTextViews(HomeDataEntity data) {
        if (data != null) {
            tv1.setText(data.todayDate);
            tv2.setText(data.bnDate);
            tv3.setText(data.location);
        }
    }
```

Viewmodel class

```
private RamadanRepository repository;
    private DisposableObserver<HomeDataEntity> disposableObserver;

    private MutableLiveData<HomeDataEntity> homeDataEntityResult = new MutableLiveData<>();

public LiveData<HomeDataEntity> homeDataEntityResult() {
        return homeDataEntityResult;
    }

public void loadHomeData() {
        disposableObserver = new DisposableObserver<HomeDataEntity>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(HomeDataEntity homeDataEntity) {
                homeDataEntityResult.postValue(homeDataEntity);

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                           }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        };

        repository.getHomeData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .debounce(400, MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribe(disposableObserver);
    }
```

Repository class

```
public Observable<HomeDataEntity> getHomeData() {
        boolean hasConnection = appUtils.isOnline();

        Observable<HomeDataEntity> observableFromApi = null;
        if (hasConnection) {
            observableFromApi = getHomeDataFromApi();
        }
        Observable<HomeDataEntity> observableFromDb = getHomeDataFromDb();

        if (hasConnection)
            return Observable.concatArrayEager(observableFromApi, observableFromDb);
        else return observableFromDb;

    }

    private Observable<HomeDataEntity> getHomeDataFromApi() {
        return apiService.getDemoHomeData()
                .map(HomeDataEntity::copyFromResponse)
                .doOnNext(homeDataDao::saveData);
    }

    private Observable<HomeDataEntity> getHomeDataFromDb() {
        return homeDataDao.getHomeData()
                .toObservable()
                .doOnNext(homeDataEntity -> {
                    Timber.d("db data %s", homeDataEntity.toString());
                });
    }
```

When app is online it also prints the roomDB inserted data after fetching. What actually am missing when app is offline?

Comment: have you checked is the data present in the local DB?

Comment: Rewrite your concatarrayeager to this Observable.concatArrayEager( observableFromDb,observableFromApi);

Comment: Does `isOnline` method work properly?

Comment: @YuriPopiv yes data is present in db

Comment: @NikolayKucheriaviy yes isOnline works properly.

Comment: @p.mathew13 rewriting that didn't work. Even data from api is not showing after rewriting

Comment: I'm not sure, but try move debounce(400, MILLISECONDS) to the top of rx chain, because debounce has own scheduler, maybe problem relates to threads. Did you catch any exceptions?